# Aggregating returns in xts object from mondays to fridays

Tags: r, xts, finance, zoo, endpoints

I have a vector of discrete returns.

```
require(xts)

set.seed(1)
x <- xts(rep(0.01,20), Sys.Date()-20:1)
colnames(x) = c("return")

> x
           return
2015-01-30   0.01
2015-01-31   0.01
2015-02-01   0.01
2015-02-02   0.01
2015-02-03   0.01
2015-02-04   0.01
2015-02-05   0.01
2015-02-06   0.01
2015-02-07   0.01
2015-02-08   0.01
2015-02-09   0.01
2015-02-10   0.01
2015-02-11   0.01
2015-02-12   0.01
2015-02-13   0.01
```

I need to aggegate the daily returns to weekly returns (monday to friday). The calculation should start on monday with `cumprod(1+x)-1` to friday. Each week the calculation starts from zero. I know how to to this with the `endpoints` function when I have a vector of prices. Unfortunately I only have returns. My new vector should look like this

```
> x
               return
2015-02-01 0.03030100
2015-02-08 0.07213535
2015-02-13 0.05101005
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `cumprod` if you want to aggregate. `cumprod` will return an observation for every observation in the object passed to it. You want `prod` instead.

Since you're defining weeks as Monday-Friday, you can do this easily with `apply.weekly`:

```
x <- xts(rep(0.01,15), as.Date("2015-02-14")-15:1)
colnames(x) <- "return"
apply.weekly(1+x, prod)-1
#                return
# 2015-02-01 0.03030100
# 2015-02-08 0.07213535
# 2015-02-13 0.05101005
```

If you're using some other week definition (e.g. Wednesday-Wednesday), then you would need to use `period.apply` with `endpoints`.

Comment: Thanks Josh! Do you have an advice where there might be a good tutorial for handling dates in R particularly for finance people?

Comment: @Pat: I don't know of one good, comprehensive tutorial, but the zoo and xts vignettes are helpful (there's also an xts-FAQ on R-Forge). The timeDate and timeSeries packages might also have useful vignettes.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try my best going through everything :)